# Restart of AlarmManager whenever application is open

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am calling this alarm manager on Background Service. Its is working on specific time like if i set it to trigger at 11:44 it will trigger but issue is whenever i open the app the alarm Manager again starts to perform the function.

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "BackgroundService";
public BackgroundService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}



@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

   // siteInAutomate();

    Log.e(TAG, "Background Activity");

    AlarmManager alarmMgr1 = 
   (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,schedule1.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 
    0,intent1, 0);

    // Intent intent0 = new Intent(this, OldEntryRemover.class);
    Log.e(TAG, "SiteOutCalled");
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,10 );
    calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 52);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    //set that timer as a RTC Wakeup to alarm manager object
    alarmMgr1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), 
    pendingIntent1);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have set the alarm for 10:52. So, if you open the app after that time, it recreates and triggers the AlarmManager immediately.

> If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately

You can check for the current time. If it is past the scheduled time, then in a instance of `Calendar` (calendar1 here), add a day

```
calendar1.add(Calendar.DATE,1)
```